# Cannot access internet or remote network after connecting to Windows VPN

Tags: windows, vpn

I set up a VPN by creating an incoming VPN connection (VPN server) in my Windows 8 machine at home (not a Windows Server).

I forwarded the PPTP port in my router (port 1723) to this machine and enabled PPTP passthrough.

In a second Windows 8 machine out of home, I created an outgoing VPN connection (VPN client). And I am able to connect to my home VPN, but I don't have access to any home resource or even internet.

UPDATE 2:

My router assigns IP addresses in a range from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.149. So I set up my incoming connection properties (VPN server) to assign IP addresses in a range from 192.168.1.150 to 192.168.1.199. Here is how it looks now:

[image: Incoming Connections Properties]

And the VPN client `ipconfig /all` output looks like this:

```
PPP adapter Kiewic VPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Kiewic VPN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.151(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 75.75.75.75
                                       75.75.76.76
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Still I am not able to access any service in my home network, including `ping` command, Remote Desktop, HTTP server, shared files.

UPDATE 3:

However, after changing the IP addresses assigned by the VPN server, the VPN client does not lose internet access when it gets connected (like it was happening before). Attaching Network Monitor to the VPN server shows HTTP traffic flowing through the VPN server.

Looking to the **Netowork and Sharing Center** at the VPN server, a **RAS (Dial-In) Interface** connection shows up as **Public** network. I can't find any way to convert it into **Private** network. This is how it looks:

[image: Netowrk And Sharing Center]

ICMP traffic is allowed on Public and Private networks in the VPN server. Still I cannot ping the machine.

The Server VPN `ipconfig /all` output is this:

```
PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.150(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Screenshots before UPDATE 2:

- VPN server:

  [image]
- VPN client:

  [image]

Comment: you don't have default gateway, set it.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh How can I set up a gateway? If I go to the vpn connection properties, click on Networking, select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click Properties, I only see the option to set "IP address", "Preferred DNS server" and "Alternate DNS server".

Comment: What is the output from the ipconfig on your client VPN machine now, after your update edit to the question?

Comment: UPDATING: The IP address is 192.168.1.155, subnet mask remains  255.255.255.255 and gateway remains emty.

Comment: @Kiewic If the behavior of the client changed when you changed the IP range for the clients, perhaps you might make just a try to see what happens when, instead of using a predefined range, you choose "Assign Ip addresses automatically using DHCP".

Comment: Regarding: Looking to the Netowork and Sharing Center at the VPN server, a RAS (Dial-In) Interface connection shows up as Public network. I can't find any way to convert it into Private network. On Windows 8, I had to modify the setting for the network in the registry as explained here: http://superuser.com/questions/662889/cannot-access-internet-or-remote-network-after-connecting-to-windows-vpn Once I modified the dial-in network to be a private network, I was able to access files on the host machine.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two articles on establishing VPN in Windows 8.
Please comment on how they compare to what you have done to create that VPN.

[Windows 8 - How to configure PPTP with Windows built-in client on Windows 8](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/315/windows-8-how-to-configure-pptp-with-windows-built-in-client-on-windows-8/p1)
[Windows 8 VPN Get Connected](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613767.aspx)

The IP address of type 169.254.x.x means that Windows wasn't able to contact a DHCP server and allocated its own temporary address.

Set the client's IP address to a static IP of 192.168.x.x so as to place it on the same network as that established by the VPN server.
Otherwise, the one is not fully accessible to the other.

Comment: These articles only talk about the client side. I have already done that. I don't see any difference with what I have already done. My guess is something is missing in the server side. I am running the VPN server also in a Windows 8 machine, not a Windows Server machine. There is an old arcticle [here](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/xp_vpn_server.htm). The problem is, after connecting to the VPN, I do not have internet access or access to other resources in the VPN. Thanks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @CanadianLuke: For the moment this doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: @harrymc Canned response; saw it was just links only, and figured you weren't spamming

Comment: @Kiewic: IP of type 169.254.x.x means that Windows wasn't able to contact a DHCP server and allocated its own. Try to set the client's address to a static IP of 192.168.x.x so it is on the same network.

Comment: I changed setting so client now gets assigned a 192.168.1.X address.

Comment: I take it that with static IP you now have Internet connectivity? Better state clearly what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant sections from your links? This is in case in the future the URLs go offline or are removed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the properties page for your vpn connection.
2. On the networking tab, select "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" and click
   [Properties].
3. Click [Advanced]
4. Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network"

Hope that cures it.

Comment: Does this refer to the client or the server?

Comment: This answer helped me. I was trying to establish the connection to the Internet while I had my Internet on, but unfortunately to no avail. I used this answer and I managed to successfully connect to the VPN with my Internet connection turned on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the network address settings. On the server, you can either point it to your DHCP server (router), or have it hand out a range of addresses. It's needs to be in the same range. Reconnect after setting it, and you should feel like you're on your LAN.

What I did on my Windows 7 server was assign a pool of 20 IP addresses, in the same range as my home network. So choose the second radio button, then type an IP address that is within your LAN, but not given out by your router. Then fill in the last box, and the second should fill itself in.

To find out what IP address range to use, open a Command Prompt window (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, select **Command Prompt**), and type `ipconfig /all` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Look at the **IPv4 Address**, **Subnet Mask**, and **Default Gateway**. If it starts with `192.168.x.y`, and the Subnet Mask is `255.255.255.0`, you have a standard Class C subnet. I would probably choose a start IP address of `192.168.x.200`, and ending IP address of `192.168.x.220`. The third number can be anything, as long as it matches the third number of your IP address.

If after all this you still can't get connected to your LAN, try checking your Firewall settings. Each firewall is different, so you may need to Google the software/hardware you're using for specific instructions. Make sure that it allows your SMB traffic (port 138/139/445) through, and likely, your DNS traffic (port 53)

Comment: What do I need to point to the DHCP server?? I am adding a screenshot of the server properties to my question.

Comment: @Kiewic I updated the answer

Comment: IP address doesn't seem to be the issue (at least not the only one). I updated my question, I will double check the Firewall and let you know.

Comment: What about manually adding the gateway on your client computer?

Answer (score -1):

On the server, make sure that the right interface is selected to get DHCP, DNS and WINS server information. for both ipv4 and ipv6. That was the issue with me, every time the network cable is disconnected from the server or from the router, windows server changes the interface for some reason.